# Sum column between zeros

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with a lot of measurement data in a column. There's a bunch of samples, with zeros in between every set of samples. The number of zeros and data points vary. To illustrate:

```
    data
    data
    data
    0
    0
    data
    data
    0
```

I want to split up the column between the zeros, so that I can manipulate each sample range by itself.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, provided your data is in column A:

```
Sub SplitData()
    dim r as Range: set r = Range("A1)
    dim outR as Range: set outR = Range("B1")
    Do While r.Value <> ""
     if r.Value <> 0 then
       if r.Row > 1 then 
         if r.Offset(-1).Value <> 0 then 
           outR.Value = r.Value: set outR = outR.offset(1)
         else 
           set outR = Cells(1,outR.Column+1): outR.Value = r.Value
           set outR = outR.Offset(1)
         end if
       else
         outR.Value = r.Value
       end if
     end if
     set r = r.offset(1)
    loop
End Sub
```